# Is the induction principle still viable if the induction skips over, or does not hold for some numbers?

Tags: induction, peano-axioms

The axiom of induction, which induction is based on can be stated as (for example in Peano axioms):

$$P(0)\wedge\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow P(S(x))) \rightarrow \forall x P(x)$$

Where P is some property of a number and S is the successor function.

This poses an interesting question, can the following theorems, which intuitively feel like they must obviously be valid be proven from the Peano axioms, (or in general).

**Theorem 1**. Consider the the induction ranging over only a subset of the natural numbers rather than over all of them. By having a similar induction rule for the subset, can we state that the property holds for the subset? Example: can we prove by induction that all even numbers have a property P by proving that 1 has that property and then that any even number k+2 has that property (assuming that even number k has that property).

**Theorem 2**. Can we say that if the induction proof fails only for some numbers, the result nonetheless holds for the rest. Example: $n+1 = n+(n-4)/(n-4)$ can be proven for all case, except for when $n=4$, so we should be able to say that the induction proof holds as long as n is not 4.

**Theorem 3**. Same as theorem 2 except now the induction would hold only after n, so that it wouldn't hold for the base case n=0.

Comment: For theorems 2 and 3 there isn't even any issue. Just consider the statements $\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(n\neq 4\implies n+1=n+\frac{n-4}{n-4}\right)$ and $\forall m\in \mathbb N\left(m\ge n\implies m+1=m+\frac{m-4}{m-4}\right)$ where $n$ is some given large enough natural number, respectively. They both can be proved by induction.

Comment: Theorem 1 isn't really a problem either. Just prove $P(2m)$ for all natural numbers $m.$ That's not to say there are no proofs that are much easier if you can generalize the method of induction a bit, but they are not quite as easy to come up with as you might think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about it this way. Let $S = \{n : P(n) \text{ is true}\}$. Then $S$ is the set of all numbers for which the proposition holds. What if, as an example, I told you that $S$ has the following few properties:

1. whenever $n$ is in $S$, then $2n$ is in $S$
2. whenever $n > 3$ is in $S$, then $n - 3$ is in $S$

You could say nothing: $S$ could be empty. But, if you know that $1$ is in $S$, then from (1) we know that $2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...$ are all in $S$; and then from (2) we know that $1, 5, 13, 29, ...$ are in $S$; and then from (1) again we know that $10, 20, 40, 80, ...$ are in $S$; and then from (2) we know that $7, 17, 37, 67, ...$ are in $S$; and then from (1) we know that $14, 34, 74, ...$ are in $S$, etcetera. It should be clear now that $S = \{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, ...\} = \mathbf{N}\setminus 3\mathbf{N}$.

The moral: don't think about whether the "induction proof holds". Instead, think about the set $S$, and its closure under your collection of implications. Typical induction has $1 \in S$ and $n \in S \implies n+1 \in S$, and in this case $S = \mathbf{N}$. Strong induction has $1 \in S$ and ($k \in S$ for all $k < n$) $\implies n \in S$. Another set of implications for which $S = \mathbf{N}$ is $1 \in S$ and $n \in S \implies 2n \in S$ and $1 < n \in S \implies n-1 \in S$: I've seen this used by Artin in his little monograph on the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: +1 very nice. I think strong induction fits into this paradigm. Maybe worth an edit to point that out.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, induction still works, but you'll either want to change the formula as a whole, or adjust the $P(x)$ formula. I'll explain below.

**Theorem 1**

First: you want to start with 0, not 1.

To work with even numbers only, you have a number of options:

- You can use P(x) to P(s(s(x))), and conclude that it is true for all even numbers, rather than for all numbers. So:

$$(P(0)\wedge\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow P(S(S(x))))) \rightarrow \forall x (Even(x) \rightarrow P(x))$$

- Alternatively, you can use:

$$(P(0)\wedge\forall x (P(2*x) \rightarrow P(2*S(x)))) \rightarrow \forall x P(2*x)$$

- Or keep the inductive axiom as it is, and use $P(x)$ : $Even(x) \rightarrow P(x)$. So then you get:

$$((Even(0) \rightarrow P(0))\wedge\forall x ((Even(x) \rightarrow P(x)) \rightarrow (Even(S(x)) \rightarrow P(S(x)))) \rightarrow \forall x (Even(x) \rightarrow P(x))$$

**Theorem 2**

Again, a few options:

- You can do 0,1,2,3 individually, and do 5 and up using induction, starting with 5:

$$(P(5)\wedge\forall x \ge 5 : (P(x) \rightarrow P(S(x)))) \rightarrow \forall x \ge 5 : P(x)$$

where $P(x) : x + 1 = x + \frac{x-4}{x-4}$

- Alternatively, keep the inductive axiom as is, and use:

$P(x) : x \not = 4 \rightarrow x + 1 = x + \frac{x-4}{x-4}$

**EDIT** (thanks @user21820 for pointing this out!)

This last expression can be used as a symbolic statement for a formal proof, but as a mathematical expression this will not do since x=4 is part of the domain and so we have an ill-defined expression given the $\frac{x-4}{x-4}$ term.

**Theorem 3**

Same thing.

- Either start with n+1:

$$(P(S(n))\wedge\forall x > n : (P(x) \rightarrow P(S(x)))) \rightarrow \forall x > n : P(x)$$

- Or keep the axiom as it is and use:

$P(x) : x > n \rightarrow \phi(x)$

Comment: I recommend pointing out that the expression "$\frac{x-4}{x-4}$" is valid **only** in a context where $x \ne 4$. So in fact your definition of $P$ in your "alternative" is invalid, because in standard logic implication is not the guarded conditional and hence both subformulae must be defined.

Comment: @user21820 Oooh, let me ponder that a minute ...

Comment: @user21820 OK, that was several minutes ... I guess the way I see it is that this is a purely formal logical expression ... so the division symbol is a function symbol that can be interpreted any which way we want. ... so ... I *think* we're ok if we were to use this in a purely formal logical proof ... but I'm not sure ... gotta think some more ... but thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809556/formal-representtion-of-cases-in-mathematics#comment3698483_1809614) for some of my comments on this issue. Unfortunately I've never seen any textbook that deals properly with this. It appears that only CS people are familiar with the guarded conditional.. In C/C++/Java[Script] syntax there is the conditional expression `( P ? x : y )` where only the relevant expression `x` or `y` is evaluated depending on the value of `P`. $P \mathrel{?\to} Q \equiv ( P \mathrel{?} Q : true )$, and here $Q$ only needs to be valid when $P$ is true.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks!  I am familiar with the guarded conditional ... but guess what, I'm from CS as well :)  In fact, in a formal logic proof this 'conditional evaluation' would happen as well: when I need to prove P(x) for the x=4 case, I say 'assume $x \not = 4$. Oh, that contradicts x=4. So, I can infer the consequent. So, conditional proven, and on to the next case.  But: that's indeed when this is treated as an expression to be used in a formal logic proof. As a mathematical expression, there is indeed a real problem, and you are absolutely right!  I'll fix it, thanks for the head up!

Comment: Yup it's a little appreciated subtlety. =) Incidentally, the problem vanishes in intuitionistic logic for exactly the same reason; to prove $A \to B$ you must start from $A$ and obtain $B$, and it does not imply $\neg A \lor B$ so we can always treat the implication as guarded in intuitionistic logic!

Comment: @user21820 interesting! I never looked into intuitionist logic .. Thanks again!

Comment: @user21820: I disagree. The same thing has come up on this site before in the context of logical conjunctions (∧); see Terry Tao's e-mail quoted at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1700580/19345. Logical conditionals (→) are the same.

Comment: @ruakh: That's what some mathematicians do, but not all. Terry is only a single person. Also, it is unambiguously **not** what first-order logic permits. So Terry does **not** describe what is the case in the current foundations of mathematics. I do however **agree** that it is extremely convenient to use the guarded boolean operations in mathematics but **not** claim that it is the logical definition as Terry is using because it conflicts with the established field of logic.

Comment: @ruakh: However, if you use a 3-value logic such as Kripke's, you can easily accommodate the "undefined" truth value and can eat [your cake](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700495/terry-tao-russells-paradox-definition-of-a-set/1700580#comment3471665_1700580). But this is not conventional.

Comment: @user21820: So, in your view, what is the first-order-logic-compatible way to express $x \neq 0 \rightarrow \frac{1}{x} \neq 0$?

Comment: @ruakh: I'll assume you read my earlier linked comments? Just to make clear, I fully support the (correct) use of guarded boolean operations in mathematics, to support ordinary mathematical practice in an intuitive way. As for how one would encode such mathematical statements in conventional first-order logic, the common trick is to define $\frac10 = 0$. You may balk at this, but this is done in many logic textbooks because they know full well that classical first-order logic does not support partial-function-symbols. Incidentally Kleene's 3-valued logic does.

Comment: @user21820: But that "trick" applies equally well to the formula in this answer; we can define $\frac{x-4}{x-4}$ arbitrarily when $x = 4$. So your original objection seems ill-founded.

Comment: @ruakh: As I said in my original comments, the trick is only found in logic textbooks and **not** in mathematical practice! Go ahead and ask a new Math SE question whether $\frac10 = 0$ and see what responses you'll get! If you don't mention logic or foundations of mathematics, they will certainly not understand why you're asking it.

Comment: Anyway you both are welcome to come over to [the logic chat-room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic) to continue discussing if you don't want to clutter up the comments here. =)

Comment: @user21820: So, as I understand it, your claims are: (1) This answer is perfectly fine according to standard mathematical practice. (2) This answer is perfectly fine according to first-order logic, provided we interpret it as logicians would. (3) This answer would be wrong according to first-order logic if we interpreted it other than as logicians do. That's . . . not very interesting. I suppose next you'll say that "I like math" is ungrammatical English if you interpret it as French.

Comment: I'm afraid you might have misunderstood my comments. I fully agree with *Bram28*'s current version of the post stating "This last expression can be used as a symbolic statement for a formal proof, but as a mathematical expression this will not do since x=4 is part of the domain and so we have an ill-defined expression given the (x−4)/(x−4) term." The first part is due to the "trick" in formal logic and the second part is due to our preference for guarded conditionals. (1) Without the caveat, it's not fine because students would think they can use logical "$\to$" in the same way as "implies".

Comment: If the original post had just written "if $x \ne 4$ then ... $\frac{x-4}{x-4}$ ..." I would have accepted it as perfectly fine "ordinary mathematics". But it uses the symbolic notation that is peculiar to first-order logic where every subexpression must be meaningful, and it's not apparent to **students** what to do with division by zero. That's all. I think we agree more than we disagree and the text-based communication is not helping. To use your helpful analogy, I'll say that "Je aimer anglais" is neither good English nor good French.